# How to Run one multithreaded task on multiple nodes with slurm

Tags: python, multithreading, slurm

As a physics major, my understanding of computers is not enough. When I use a python package name tenpy, because of the need for calculation speed, multi-thread calculation is required. In the document of this package, it says that

```
How can I set the number of threads TeNPy is using?
Most algorithms in TeNPy don’t use any parallelization besides what the underlying BLAS provides,
so that depends on how you installed TeNPy, numpy and scipy! 
Using for example an export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 
should limit it to 4 threads under usual setups, 
but you might also want to export MKL_NUM_THREADS=4 instead, 
if you are sure that you are using MKL.
```

so l try to run my code in one node as

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -N 1    
#SBATCH -p normal   
#SBATCH -J com_pro
#SBATCH -c 32 
#SBATCH --nodelist=cu08
#SBATCH -o component_pro.txt         

if [ -f "/public/soft/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
    . "/public/soft/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
 else
     export PATH="/public/soft/anaconda3/bin/:$PATH"
fi

conda activate tenpy
cd /public/name/envs/node

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=32
srun -N 1 -n 1 -c 32 python component_pro.py
```

This may true.

However, a more complicated problem arises when I want to run a (code) task on **multiple nodes** due to RAM limitations ,and want to use two nodes at the same time .I don't know how to do it. I have seen a lot The slurm documentation, but the  explanation of parameters such as -n -c --ntasks-per-node still confuses me. I think -c, that is, -cpu-per-task is important, but by reading the documentation of slurm .I also know that I in this situation l need parameters such as -N 2, but it is confusing how to write it

I sincerely hope to get help from the community, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question is off-topic, but the answer is that you can't do what you want to do. Check how you installed BLAS/numpy/scipy/TeNPy and follow their directions. If some of your particular libraries explain how to use multiple nodes, follow those directions. Chances are that the code is only multithreaded (by any means, threads, OpenMP...) and that is the only option you will have.